# Django log messages not processing correctly. Messages to multiple files

Tags: python, django, logging

So I have two loggers in my Django project. One for authentication failures, and one which includes those but also includes messages for when something is edited (basically everything for which I have a logger command).
I seem to have a bit of a problem in modules where I want to use both loggers however. My two loggers are currently defined like so:

```
'': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'INFO',
    'propagate': True,
},
'auth': {
    'handlers': ['file_auth'],
    'level': 'CRITICAL',
    'propagate': True,
}
```

And my handlers are:

```
'file': {
    'level': 'INFO',
    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
    'filename': '/home/debug.log',
    'formatter': 'simple',
},
'file_auth': {
    'level': 'CRITICAL',
    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
    'filename': '/home/debug2.log',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
},
```

At the top of my Django view, I have

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger = logging.getLogger('auth')
```

Then within one view I have a logger.info(message).
If I change this to logger.critical(message), the message appears in both log files but if it remains as logger.info, nothing happens at all.

(Probably useless information...at the start of my LOGGING section in settings.py, I have:

```
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
```

Not sure if they have any relevance. But previously I was struggling to get the errors to appear in both files until I switched the order of introducing them which magically changed stuff - I really don't understand why that would make a difference though)

Would be really grateful if someone could help me out....Probably really simple but I must admit I don't really understand how it works..

Comment: Python logger is a Singleton, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117547/strange-behaviour-on-my-logging-class

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how this helps. I call two different loggers right? logger = logging.getLogger('') and logger=logging.getLogger('auth')....Oh I see...I have just overwritten the first with the second? So I should call them logger1 and logger2, or at least give them different names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different loggers, named `''` (the root logger) and `'auth'`. The order in which your two statements appear:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger = logging.getLogger('auth')
```

obviously makes a difference when you call

```
logger.info(...)
```

as in the two cases you will be calling the method on two different loggers. You might wish to change your code to

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger = logging.getLogger('auth')
```

and then call methods on either `root_logger` or `logger` as appropriate.